# How to observe (chain?) an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I've got various Angular components which make use of a shared Angular 'mediator' service to get data and do other processing. This mediator service also goes on to make various HTTP calls on behalf of its components and in these cases it returns the observables from http.request to the components, for them to subscribe and trigger the http call. However, I need my mediator service to be able to see the responses as they come in, in order to capture information from them, as/before the components get their 'next' calls. Of course, I don't want my mediator to trigger the http calls if the components never subscribe.

I can see various ways of achieving this, but I'm unsure what the best practice is. Should the mediator service make a hot observable out of the http call and create a new observable for the components to subscribe to? But then how elegant is it to chain them so that the service doesn't trigger the http calls? Alternatively I can easily get this working by implementing a pipe/map function (and passing the data straight through after copying it), but this doesn't seem like what map was designed to do.

Is there another pattern that I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for the tap() operator.

Comment: Or maybe [`share()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html)

Comment: tap() was exactly what I needed. I had seen references to do() but I hadn't realised that pipe/tap was the new version of that. Thanks very much!